# How to open HTML on another computer?

Tags: html

I created an html webpage for my project but the file cannot be opened by my teacher using his computer even after saving all the files in the webpage.

Comment: What error is your teacher getting when she opens the html page on her computer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a teacher not being able to open homework

Answer (score 0):

You just have to send the link address to the other computer and then you need to copy the html focus and it will be sent to the other computer

Comment: how do you perform - `Send the link address to the other computer`?